# Feed web tile with authentication possible?

Tags: authentication, rss, feed, microsoft-band

Is it possible to add a feed that needs authentication as a web tile in Microsoft Band? I can not find any example or api description for it.

In the [documentation (pdf)](https://developer.microsoftband.com/Content/docs/Microsoft%20Band%20Web%20Tile%20Documentation.pdf) is only noted that I need to secure the rss feed with ssl if I like to use authentication:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now use an API key in the url params and secure the connection with SSL. Think this is what the doc tries to say.